# how will i transfer a value from a gridview of a previous page to another web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

how can i pass the value from the gridview to the next webform? here is my gridview code below:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID ="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="View" PostBackUrl='<%# "Details.aspx?RowIndex=" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate
</asp:TemplateField>
```

but i can't seem to make it work. it goes to the next form but does not get the value. my id has a format "1000001" and it does read it.

here is my code for the next page. i created a new gridview just to store the value from.

```
 int rowIndex = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]);
 GridView gv1 = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1");
 GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
 lblID.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
```

Comment: You having problem  getting query string value or getting prev. page control (`GridView`) ?

Comment: it doesnt read the rowindex that was read

Comment: You need to redirect to next page like Details.aspx?RowIndex=100001 ? and then read RowIndex as QueryString on next page, right ?

Comment: Does your query string have any value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand"` like

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView"  OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand"
```

Update your Columns as

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID ="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName= "Redirect" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' ></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate
```

In Code-Behind file

```
        protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Redirect") {
                //Get Command Argument
                Response.Redirect("Details.aspx?RowIndex="+e.CommandArgument.ToString(),true);                    
            }
        }
```